# How to override Shopping Cart total in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using gloudemans package to build a shopping cart. How do I override Cart::total() so it can output a different value if a user enters a coupon?

For example,

```
Cart::total() = 200;
$coupon = 20;
Cart::total() = 180;
```

Comment: https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/issues/128

Comment: Thanks. So I must do that in checkout. Not good though.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command for getting cart.php file in your config/cart.php

**php artisan vendor: publish --provider="Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider" --tag="config"**

after that you will get this file you have to update the tax amount from cart.php file like this

Before
[image]

After
[image]

and after update you need to do clear your cart and add cart item to your cart page

Answer (score 0):

if you use total method laravel shopping cart add tax to real total of prices just use `Cart::subtotal()` to get real to total of prices without adding tax to it.